# Getting Next Transaction Number

Tags: sql, sqlite

My Transaction_ID (varchar) contains following pattern

```
DXB1
DXB2
.....
DXB15
...
DXB200
```

The next transaction_id would be DXB201, How to get that one from SQL Query

I am using

```
SELECT  MAX(transaction_id) AS Expr1
FROM    transaction_master
WHERE   (transaction_id LIKE 'DXB%')
```

but it fails to give correct output after i.e. query returns DXB9 even though DXB15 is present

Comment: That's what string sorting does.  You need to pull out the numeric component.  What DBMS product are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: Your problem is you're asking your RDBMS to treat a varchar like a number.  Your query is giving you the correct result in lexigraphic terms; "DXB9" is indeed greater than "DXB15" (it would come later in an alphabetical sort)

Comment: @Siyual :  I am using SQLite as a backend C# as a front  end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the characters following the `DXB` portion are numeric, the following should work:

```
Select  'DXB' || Next As NextTransactionId
From
(
  Select    Max(Cast(Replace(Transaction_Id, 'DXB', '') As Int)) + 1 As Next
  FROM      transaction_master
  WHERE     (transaction_id LIKE 'DXB%')
)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9bfe4/12/0)